# Passing Template Function into Template Function

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, templates

A lot of this question is probably impractical to use in the real world but I'm doing this as a learning process.

I have started a project documenting each type of sorting algorithm and it's efficiency. I have been writing each sorting algorithm as a template function in c++ like as follows:

```
template <class T>
void bubble_sort(T arr[], int numItems) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numItems - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                T temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want my driver program to test each algorithms efficiency over a few sets of data and want to generalize my process a bit more by creating a template function that tests each sorting algorithm, but I have no idea how to do that. Here's what I'm thinking but it's not working:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
double test(F arr[], int numItems, T func) {

    clock_t start, finish;
    start = clock();
    T(arr, numItems);
    finish = clock();

    return (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

}
```

The contents of the test don't matter, but I want to be able to pass in the sorting function like this:

```
    double duration = test<int>(arr, numItems, bubble_sort<int>);
```

Any help in building this function would be better;

Comment: What exactly is the error? Also, why not `std::function<void(F[]. int)>` as the third argument of test?

Comment: A function is no type. But you can easily put a static function into a struct and pass the type of the struct. Then you can call Foo::bar() in the template class/function.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to call `func()`, inside `test()`, as

```
func(arr, numItems);
```

instead of

```
T(arr, numItems);
```